# js - 2 variables assigned but only 1 working

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have 2 variables. One is assigned inside a `.then` and the other assigned in a function. Later on only 1 is defined.

Code excerpt...

```
let user;
let station;
const app = express();

app.post("/api/user", (req, res) => {
    user = req.body.user; // Breakpoint added here to confirm user set
}

// Uses serialport module. Called when data received on serial port
function serialPortListener(data) {
    getStation(data) // Retrieves record from database
    .then(s => {
        station = s; // Breakpoint added here to confirm station set
    ...
}
```

I set breakpoints on both methods to confirm the variables are set. When I try to access them, later on, only `user` is defined. I'm assuming it's something to do with the context in which `station` is set?

`station` is not assigned anywhere else.

Comment: please put `getStation` function also.It seems that function is not returning value, therefore it is giving undefined.

Comment: is the promise getStation() resolved?
Did you check if the line station = s was called?

Comment: "I set breakpoints..." including on `station = s` to confirm it was set

Comment: I had the same problem just yesterday; it's because return/ variable set from inside an asynchronous function does not work... [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnBimoVllfo&t=73s) helped me to understand it, look at his syntax and try to implement it in your application.

Comment: I think someone is using something synchronously when it is asynchronous. AKA You order a pizza and as soon as you order you try to eat it. Not going to happen.

Answer (score -5):

I believe the problem is due to the way `var` and `let` works. Try changing `let` with `var`, it should work. For the differences between `var` and `let` read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var).

Edit: Ran the code here is a working code.

```
let user;
let station = 'ABC';

let getStation = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('XYZ'), 1000);
});

// Uses serialport module. Called when data received on serial port
function serialPortListener(data) {
    getStation
    .then((s) => {
        console.log(station); // station is available with value ABC
        station = s;
        console.log(station); // station has value changed to XYZ
    });
}

console.log(serialPortListener('data'));
```

The problem in your codes is in the line

```
 getStation(data)
```

Comment: No that's not the reason here

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: `let station = serialPortListener(xxx).then(s => return s);`
```function serialPortListener(data) {
    return getStation(data)
}
```
I think it should be something similar to this but I'm still at the beginning of understanding asynchronous functions. Have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnBimoVllfo).